# Texture messes up after extruding a modified plane

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, extrude

I want to make some 3d models of pixel art. I started by adding a plane, adding a texture to it, added loop cuts to my plane, 15 loop cuts because it's a 16x16 texture, then I selected the blank faces and deleted them.

As I extrude this plane, <kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>E</kbd> > $0.1$, the texture messes up on the edge of the item, as shown below

[image]

Although not all faces mess up on the edge, a lot still do. I tried recalculating normals, unwrapping the object again, but I ended with the same problem, no change at all. Though I may have done it wrong, since I never did it before.

**I tried smart UV project and cube projection, but they just mess it up even more.**

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error results from anti-aliasing / inaccuracy / interpolation of the UV across faces. A solution is to get each face to read from a single point in the image.

This involves a couple more steps than it should, IMO.. it should not be necessary to split the geometry to do this, seams should do the job... but still, in 2.91, they don't.

You've probably already done most of this.. starting in the flat, with a simple plane:

1. Subdivide your plane with 15 cuts for 16x16 pixels, as you have.
2. Edit mode, Edge, All selected, right-click menu > *Edge Split*
3. UV Edit.. <kbd>U</kbd> *Unwrap > Project from View (Bounds)*
4. With the pivot in the UV Edit window set to *2D cursor*, select all, move faces so the bottom left of the map is at the bottom left of the texture, select the vertex there, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> snap the cursor to it.
5. Scale the map in X and Y so each face covers a pixel..

[image]

6. And as above, switch pivot to 'Individual Origins', and scale the UV faces to 0.
7. Back in the 3D View, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *Merge > By Distance*, weld the faces in the geometry back together.

Now the result of an extrusion or *Solidify* modifier will be clean.

[image]

Comment: Took me a while to figure out why it wasn't working, when I realized I needed to do this with a fresh project, as this must be done on a none extruded plane. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you, here's my first small project on 3d pixel art in blender! https://ibb.co/wWbkydK

Comment: @MaxAnimator  Yay! Thanks for sharing! Will edit answer, to make it a bit clearer.